# Using scope within an ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to put a string underneath an ng-repeated name, but it isn't showing up when I put it in as if its just from a normal scope with {{}}.

Also when I put it in an ng-repeat with a list, it prints the whole thing out very widely like its separating each letter into each part of the list, so that's obviously not going to do.

I just need it to print out the importance level beneath the name from the object.

```js
$scope.profileCompare = {

        You: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
            percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Unimportant"
        },
        Pizza: {
            questionAnswer: [true, false, false, false, false, false],
            percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Very important"
        },
        Greenie: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, true, false],
            percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Important"
        }
    }
```

```html
 <div ng-repeat-start="(key, value) in profileCompare" style="float: left">{{key}} <br> 
  <ul class="comparison-list">
    <li ng-repeat="importance in value.questionImportance track by $index">
      {{importance}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <ul ng-repeat-end class="comparison-list" style="float: right">
    <li ng-repeat="answer in value.questionAnswer track by $index" style="position:relative; " class="fa-li fa" ng-class="{green:answer, red:!answer, 'fa-check-square':answer, 'fa-square':!answer}">
    </li>
    <br>
    <li ng-repeat="percent in value.percent track by $index" style="position:relative; float:right">
      {{percent}}
  </li>
```

Comment: why are you using `ng-repeat` for `questionImportance` when it is a string?

Comment: Because doing it the other way didn't work. That was what the question was about. Does that work.

Comment: doing it what other way? no ...using ng-repeat for a non array/object makes no sense

Comment: That's the entire point of this question. It was included because I tried it and it was a failure, and I made a note of it. 

The entire point of the question is how to get the string in there.

Comment: don't repeat it,  just print it

Comment: This is the point. That is not working.

Comment: what's not working? You haven't showed what you tried...just said it doesn't work. Create a  demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: What's not working? Scope bindings {{thing here}} are not working when there is no ng-repeat but just the scope bindings which should get the string.

Comment: again...show the expression used ...in other words your code. Have you tried using `{{value.questionImportance}}`

Comment: @realization mock your result and repost it here. What you state is obviously not getting you the right feedback.

Comment: Ah great {{value.questionImportance}} is what I was looking for. I had thought that isn't the way it works, that questionImportance was the value, but in ng-repeat scenarios value is just a keyword to point to the properties within an object, which is the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% certain that I understand what you want, but I am going to make some assumptions.

I changed your object slightly so that it is wrapped in an array and also pushed the "name" into its own property.

```
$scope.profileCompare = [{
    name: 'You',
    stats: {
        questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
        percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
        questionImportance: "Unimportant"
    }
}, {
    name: 'Pizza',
    stats: {
        questionAnswer: [true, false, false, false, false, false],
        percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
        questionImportance: "Very important"
    }
}, {
    name: 'Greenie',
    stats: {
        questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, true, false],
        percent: ['20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
        questionImportance: "Important"
    }
}];
```

Here is how you could represent this in a few unordered lists. Again, I do not understand what you are trying to achieve really, but I hope this gets you to where you need to go:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="profile in profileCompare" class="header">{{profile.name}}   
</div>
<div>
    {{profile.stats.questionImportance}} 
</div>
<ul ng-repeat="qanswer in profile.stats.questionAnswer track by $index">
    <li>{{qanswer}}</li>
</ul>  
<ul ng-repeat="pct in profile.stats.percent track by $index">
    <li>{{pct}}</li>
</ul>   
<div ng-repeat-end>
    <br />
</div>
```

**[jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/raigsingh/nfu8gLko/)**

Comment: I'm trying to get the questionImportance variable to print to the dom element for each object.

Comment: Did you look at my jsfiddle. It prints the questionImportance directly under the name. Each "name" property belongs to its own object within an array. I believe that much is very clear. If it is still not correct. Make an HTML in jsfiddle and post your desired result clearly because I don't think anyone else is going to understand your needs.